# New macro and glossary entry in a command

Tags: macros, glossaries

I want to unify the creation of a macro and the addition of a new entry to the glossary in a single command using the `glossaries` package. A call to the command would ideally look like

```
\mycommand{powerset}{\operatorname{Pow}(#1)}{A}{Power set of A}
```

The first argument specifies the name of the new macro: `\powerset`, the second is the definition of this macro. In this case, `\powerset` expects one argument and produces as result `\operatorname{Pow}(#1)`.

The last two arguments are related with the glossary entry. The first argument is the default parameter for the newly created macro. The name of the glossary entry should be the macro called with the default parameter - in math mode. In this case, `\powerset{A}`. Finally, the last argument is the description of the glossary entry. In this example, the glossary entry should look like

```
\newglossaryentry{powerset}
{
     name=\ensuremath{\operatorname{Pow}(A)},
     description=Power set of A
}
```

Any ideas? Also, how hard is to extend this process to include a specified amount of parameters like

```
\mycommand{complement}{2}{#1 \setminus #2}{A}{B}{The complement of B in A}?
```

The motivation under the question is to provide the ability to define macros that will be added to the glossary after first use with the proper link to the page where they have been first used.

Comment: The first part of the question is possible of course, the second is very complex ('arbitrarily many parameters'), but I don't think you will gain much by such an approach. You define `\powerset` for which purpose?

Comment: Your last request is possible, but I wouldn't recommend it, and am not sure how to implement it, atm.

Comment: @Skillmon We can focus on solving the original question for now. The arbitrarily many parameters one is just an extra.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might do (I never used the `glossaries` package before, so don't know what to test):

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{glossaries}
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\mycommand}{m m m m}{%
    \expandafter\newcommand\expandafter{\csname #1\endcsname}[1]{#2}%
    \newglossaryentry{#1}{%
        name=\ensuremath{\csname #1\endcsname{#3}},%
        description=#4%
    }%
}

\makeglossaries

\mycommand{powerset}{\operatorname{Pow}(#1)}{A}{Power set of A}

\begin{document}
\printglossary[style=altlist,title=Glossar]
\gls{powerset}
$\powerset{c}$
\end{document}
```

The following provides the possibility of optionally adding *two* more arguments (but you might encounter problems with grouping after that command; also the code might not be pretty)

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\mycommand}{m m m m g g}{%
    \IfNoValueTF{#6}{%
        \IfNoValueTF{#5}{%
            \expandafter\newcommand\expandafter{\csname #1\endcsname}[1]{#2}%
            \newglossaryentry{#1}{%
                name=\ensuremath{\csname #1\endcsname{#3}},%
                description=#4%
            }%
        }%
        {%
            \expandafter\newcommand\expandafter{\csname #1\endcsname}[2]{#2}%
            \newglossaryentry{#1}{%
                name=\ensuremath{\csname #1\endcsname{#3}{#4}},%
                description=#5%
            }%
        }%
    }%
    {%
        \expandafter\newcommand\expandafter{\csname #1\endcsname}[3]{#2}%
        \newglossaryentry{#1}{%
            name=\ensuremath{\csname #1\endcsname{#3}{#4}{#5}},%
            description=#6%
        }%
    }%
}
```

Comment: `\makeglossaries` is missing before `\mycommand` usage

Comment: @ChristianHupfer as I said, I have no idea of how to use that package :)

Comment: Does 'xparse' provide any features that can not be achieved with regular LaTeX code in this case?

Comment: @MartinAzpillaga: I think in this case you could use `\newcommand` as well instead of the `\NewDocumentCommand`

Comment: @MartinAzpillaga Since you might code anything without it, no. And in this case it's not really necessary, but for your last request it would make things a lot easier, I guess.

Comment: I see. This works as expected, great job. I should say that my motivation includes using the glossary entry in the definition of the macro so that an automatic link to the first use is included in the glossary.

Comment: How hard is it to extend this solution to any amount of parameters, possibly announced in the call to mycommand?

Comment: @MartinAzpillaga I've added one more optional argument delimited by `{}`. And here one can see one of the additional features of `xparse`... Note that the `g` type argument is not recommended to use!

Comment: @MartinAzpillaga and as I said, I don't know how to expand this to an arbitrary number of options. I do encounter some problems there which I don't know how to solve. Maybe you should wait for someone with more expertise than myself.

Comment: @Skillmon In the meantime I have noticed that for now, I would only need this command for macros with up to 3 arguments. Now that we are using xparse, how about taking the arguments from a comma separated list using \SplitList?

Comment: @MartinAzpillaga I've made another edit to support up to three arguments. But for introducing any `\SplitList` parsing I'm definitely too tired. Tweak it as you like, good night.

Comment: I accept this answer as it does answer the original question. I will create a new question for the generic case.